# Efficiently count trailing zeros of numbers from a factorial

Tags: python, algorithm, performance, primes, factorial

I am trying to calculate the number of trailing zeroes in a factorial with python per [this](http://www.codewars.com/kata/52f787eb172a8b4ae1000a34/train/python) problem. Thus far, my solution looks like this:

```
import math
def zeros(n):
    return len(str(math.factorial(n))) - len(str(math.factorial(n)).rstrip('0'))
```

This works on smaller numbers, but one of the tests is `1000000000!`, and the inefficiency of my algorithm causes the system to break.

I have struggled with making algorithm efficiency in the past, and would appreciate any general advice on this subject, as well as any specific pointers to what could make this algorithm more efficient.

Comment: The number of 0 at the end of a number is the number of times the factor 10 appears in the number. You definitely should use this property to get an efficient algorithm to answer this question.

Comment: See [this](http://www.purplemath.com/modules/factzero.htm)

Comment: It's kinda weak that I was locked out of posting an answer I was typing because the question was closed. My answer focuses on removing programmatic redundancy (which in this case doesn't compare to the mathematical reductions but is a more general approach). Link: https://pastebin.com/4a51WQgZ

Comment: It might seem obvious, but these are *decimal* zeros (i.e. base 10 or radix 10). The answer is different for different bases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than evaluating the factorial computing the length directly, it would be best to use algebraic properties.

For example, rather than accumulating the total, track the number of multiples of two and five.

Comment: Fives are enough.